# Ubercart: Attributes?

Tags: 6, ubercart

I've got an existing cart and the inventory has separate products for different weights and they're separate entries. I want the varying weights to be combined and searched by attributes. What's the best way to do this with ubercart.

I'm using drupal 6 ubercart 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubercart 2.x has built in support for creating product classes with attributes. See the [documentation](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/10961/product_attributes_and_options) for more information

Comment: When i create a class it creates a product type. that doesn't seem like what i wanted.

Comment: I don't suppose you read the documentation link I posted? It goes on to explain that after you create a class you can then create attributes. Attributes can be attached to classes. For instance, a clothing product class may have 'size' and 'colour' as attributes